# Visual Studio 2013 always opens a website in IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I am having a website in ASP.Net 4.0 in VS2010 that works of  IIS localhost and not IIS Express or VS local dev server.  When I open this same website in VS 2013 ( File > Open Web Site...), it always uses IIS Express ( and not IIS) as in screen shot below.

Is there any way I could use the regular IIS ( not the express version) and also, can I change VS 2013 to show IIS websites and not IIS Express sites i.e. make VS 2013 use regular IIS?

[image: VS2013 always uses IIS Express and not regular IIS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Visual Studio as an Administrator, it should let you access and open IIS Sites OR IIS Express Sites.

[image: IIS Sites]

IIS Express is pretty much the same thing as IIS. The only major difference is that IIS Express does not have a configuration UI. You have to handle everything through the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. Having no IIS Express management console is the problem. I think IIS regular is more developer friendly.